# Davinci resolve 15 on Ubuntu 16

Tags: 16.04

I installed davinci resolve on the ubuntu 16.04, however when I get mp4 video clips in the dainvci resolve it doesn't play. Pointer on the timeline runs but it doeesn't play(audo/video) anyting.

Any suggestion/pointer for this ssue?

Comment: Not sure if it helps but did you installed additional codecs? If not you may try `ubuntu-restricted-extras` (also includes Microsoft TTF fonts).

Comment: I haven't , i will try that.

Comment: installing ubuntu-restricted-extra didn't help :(

Comment: Can you reproduce the same file with regular media players?

Comment: Yup, it plays fine in VLC. it is mp4 file

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add that info. I'm preparing an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The free version of DaVinci Resolve doesn't support h.264 or AAC. You would need to buy the Studio version to get support for these codecs. Resolve doesn't work with ffmpeg or gstreamer underneath, but its own engine.

Answer (score 0):

Davinci Resolve 15 supports the **MP4** container with **H.264 codec** only, according to the ["supported codec list"](http://documents.blackmagicdesign.com/DaVinciResolve/20180406-341247/DaVinci_Resolve_15_Supported_Codec_List.pdf).

The full information about a media file can be obtained, for example,  with [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download/Ubuntu). This software is available at the Ubuntu repositories and can be installed with Ubuntu Software or by any other of the usual means, no need to download it from the previous link.

If the file needs re-encoding to comply with Davinci Resolve's requirements there are many video converters available, the free and open-source [HandBrake](https://handbrake.fr/) being one of the easiest to use. This software is also available in the Ubuntu repositories.

For community/professional support you can go to the [Blackmagic Forum](http://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/).